# How to manually gzip files for web and Amazon CloudFront

Tags: web, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I have a 3MB .wasm file which I'm trying to compress using gzip and used on Amazon CloudFront. Currently CloudFront doesn't support auto compressing .wasm file types.

I used `gzip filename.wasm` but the outputted result isn't working in my code when fetched from CloudFront. I read elsewhere that the file is missing some file headers.

So my question is, how can I manually gzip a .wasm file for use on web and fetched from CloudFront?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait - so you manually `gzip` the file, and you're trying to fetch that file through CloudFront, and it doesn't unzip? A few questions: (1) are you compressing/uncompressing properly (ie: does the zipped file work without going through CloudFront)? (2) Are you invalidating the CloudFront cache of your object between test attempts? (CloudFront is just a simple cache at it's core - it's not going to modify contents of your files - maybe you're receiving an older cached copy)

Answer (score 3):

You can compress the file with gzip, and upload it to s3 using `--content-type application/wasm --content-encoding gzip`, without the `.gz` suffix. When this file is then served through cloudfront, it will be returned gzipped and readable by the browser.

Here is an example using brotli:

```
WASM_FILE=$(ls dist/ | grep '.wasm$');
brotli-cli dist/*.wasm
BROTLI_FILE=$(ls dist/ | grep wasm.br);
mv dist/$BROTLI_FILE dist/$WASM_FILE

aws s3 cp dist/*.wasm s3://$S3_BUCKET/ \
  --content-encoding br \
  --content-type application/wasm
```